# Capturing iPhone Keyboard Next button press event in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, forms

How does one capture Previous and Next button events with JS/Jquery on an iPhone keyboard? I'm trying to get this to populate a field in a form.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to capture the button presses themselves, but since their purpose is to move focus from one field to the next, you could capture the `blur` and `focus` events and work from those.

Of course the events will also fire at other times, so depending on your intention you might want to do something like listen for a blur then a subsequent focus on the adjacent form field, though you'll never be 100% sure that it was fired by pressing one of the buttons.

Comment: Tried that out. Didn't get anything on focus OR blur. It's as if the keyboard itself was in a totally different frame completely. The events didn't fire at all, which was the strange part to all this.